# How do I stop my sidebar from scrolling when it reaches its end?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sidebar on my page and it scrolls with the page content as it should. The problem is that the sidebar is considerably shorter than the content so it scrolls off the top of the page. I would like the sidebar to stop scrolling once it reaches it's end. I need the main content to keep scrolling obviously.
I have tried doing with js and css, but couldn't get it to work. addClass seems like it should work, but I was unsuccessful.
This is my latest attempt:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

     if (scroll >= 100) {
        $("#stick").addClass("stick-after");
    }
});
```

```css
#stick{
    position:relative;
}
.stick-after{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container' style='background-color:pink'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-lg-9 bg-warning'>
            <h3>
                main content here...</h3>            
        </div>
        <div class='col-lg-3 sidebar' id='stick'>
            <div class='content'> some text....<br><br>
            </div>
            <div class='content'> some text....<br><br>
           ...
            ...
            </div>
            <div class='footer'>
                FOOTER LINKS
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code gets the background-color to change, but the content of the div still scrolls up and off the page. I have also tried this: .stick-after{position:fixed; top:95hv;} still scrolls.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong or a better way to do it is appreciated.

Comment: Please post whatever relevant code and what you have tried...

Comment: Two typos in `postion:fixed:`

Comment: thanks. but still not work:(